# Add button to order shipping back-office

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How can i add a new button in prestashop's back office in order shipping table.

Specific, i want it to be from a module not the file _shipping.tpl .

Thanks[image]

Comment: You can't. You have to edit /themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_shipping.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Edit backoffice/themes/default/template/controllers/orders/_shipping.tpl and if you want add a new hook for you module.

Regards